# Can't wrap my head around a mapping of mappings

Tags: solidity, erc-721

I'm trying to fully comprehend what is going on in a standard ERC721 token.

But this statement is really tripping me up:

```
// Mapping from owner to operator approvals
mapping (address => mapping (address => bool)) internal operatorApprovals;
```

Like what is a good way to think about a `mapping` of a `mapping`,


Like could someone please give me a minimalist example of why this is a useful data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the **mappings** as a sort of an array where the key can be any type (instead of just a numerical index) like the associative arrays in PHP or the Hashtable in C#. And two nested mappings just provide you another level with the same feature.

So to use that mapping in this way

```
operatorApprovals[owner_address][operator_address]
```

to get the bool value

```
operatorApprovals[owner_address]
```

will only give you the other mapping which can contains multiple *operators*. Keys are unique. Check the [Solidity doc](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#mappings) for more info

Comment: Great explanation. I think it finally clicked for me.